# Type mismatch when trying to slice a multidimensional array

Tags: vba, excel

I've got an array which is stored in a dictionary it's bounds are from (0 to 29 and 0 to 7) and stores a mixture of strings and integers.

I'm trying to get one column of it without looping however every time I do I get a type mismatch error.

I've seen that there is a limit on the size of an array that you can use with application.index but it is no way near that limit.

```
Dim tmp As Variant

' Get Array from Public Dictionary
tmp = FBList(214)

' Output a string of values from one column of array
Debug.Print Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(tmp, 19, 0), ",")
```

I always get type mismatch on the last line. I have successfully used this with other arrays but not this time.

[Example File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/imle59brj1yprg1/ArraySlicingExample.xlsm?dl=0)

> ***Update: Populating FBList***
>
> ```
> Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, NoCol As Integer, si As Integer, sKey As Integer
>
> Set cn = Nothing
>
> With FBList
>     .RemoveAll
>     .CompareMode = TextCompare
> End With
> With FBMap
>     .RemoveAll
>     .CompareMode = TextCompare
> End With
>
> If UserList.Count = 0 Or ThisUser = "" Then Call UserDL
>
> Call ConnecttoDB
> Set cmd = New ADODB.Command: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
>
> With cmd
>     .CommandTimeout = 120
>     .ActiveConnection = cn
>     .CommandText = "CSLL.Reports"
>     .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
>     .Parameters.refresh
>     .Parameters("@Alias").value = ThisUser
>     On Error GoTo NoConnection
>     Set rs = .Execute
>     On Error GoTo 0
> End With
>
> With rs
>     For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
>         If i = 0 Then
>             FBMap.Add .Fields.Item(0).Name, "Key"
>         Else
>             FBMap.Add .Fields.Item(i).Name, i - 1
>         End If
>     Next i
>
>     NoCol = .Fields.Count - 2
>
>     If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
>         .MoveLast
>         .MoveFirst
>             While (Not .EOF)
>                     With FBList
>                         ReDim UStemp(0 To NoCol, 0) As Variant
>                         sKey = rs("ID")
>                         If Not .Exists(sKey) Then
>                             For i = 1 To NoCol + 1
>                                 UStemp(i - 1, 0) = rs(i)
>                             Next i
>                             .Add sKey, UStemp
>                         ElseIf .Exists(sKey) = True Then
>                             si = UBound(FBList(sKey), 2)
>                             ReDim UStemp(0 To NoCol, 0 To si + 1)
>                             For j = 0 To si + 1
>                                 If j <= si Then
>                                     For i = 0 To NoCol
>                                         UStemp(i, j) = .Item(sKey)(i, j)
>                                     Next i
>                                 ElseIf j > si Then
>                                     For i = 0 To NoCol
>                                         UStemp(i, j) = rs(i + 1)
>                                     Next i
>                                 End If
>                             Next j
>                             .Remove sKey
>                             .Add sKey, UStemp
>                         End If
>                     End With
>                 .MoveNext
>             Wend
>         .MoveFirst
>     End If
> End With
>
> Set cmd = Nothing: Set rs = Nothing: Set cn = Nothing
> ```
>
> -------- @Vityata Please look at this:
>
> ```
> Option Explicit
> Public Sub ProofOfSlicingWithArray()
>     Dim tmp(1 To 10, 1 To 10) As Variant
>     Dim i As Long, j As Long
>
>     ' Populate multi-dimensional array
>     For i = 1 To 10
>         For j = 1 To 10
>             tmp(i, j) = Int((999 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
>         Next j
>     Next i
>
>     Debug.Print Join(Application.Index(tmp, 5, 0), ",")
>
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: show how you are filling `FBList`

Comment: Just curious - have you used index with arrays? I thought it only works with ranges - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd

Comment: @Vityata [Have a look at this](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/)

Comment: Hi, I looked it. varArray is a range there. And is it in your case?

Comment: @Vityata Have a look at my update. I've added proof that you can use it with arrays

Comment: Well, the only thing I can say is - can you put a stop before `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(tmp, 19, 0)` and check what do you have in tmp? Is it array? How does it look like? Is 0 allowed? (Because in the index formula in excel, you are forced to start from 1.

Comment: @Vityata The Array gets populated correctly. I've stopped it the line before and checked the values and they're there. I've also used `typename(tmp)` and it returns `variant()`. I was wondering about base 0 working as well, so I forced base 1 with the array and I still got the same error

Comment: Can you create a minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )? Since you populate this dictionary of arrays from some unspecified database, no one but you can reproduce what you see.

Comment: Is the problem with the `Index` or the `Join`? ie, what info do you get when you put a watch on `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(tmp, 19, 0)`?

Comment: @bobajob It's from the index, I've tried splitting it into two rows as well. John Coleman - I'm just trying to build a better example

Comment: Are you sure `tmp` isn't empty?

Comment: 100% I can print it to sheet

Comment: @JohnColeman I've added an example file to my question. with an example data output of what comes from the datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error happens because `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index` is limited to 255 characters and your array's values sometimes exceed it.

Exactly as `Application.Transpose(vArray)` which I used to put in my code, it is a convenient solution, but 65536 row limit and 255 character limit make it unreliable, now I only use a custom function for transposition.